# Trying to update thousands of rows in a MySQL table from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying update rows in a table (called "users") based on values found in another table (called "users_temp"). I have the query:

```
UPDATE users
INNER JOIN users_temp on users_temp.email = users.email
SET users.list_id = users_temp.list_id
```

Both tables have about 50k rows and this query basically just crashes MySQL.

Can someone suggest a better way of doing this or tell me why MySQL is crashing?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "crashes MySQL" mean? Your query is ok. To boost the performance, try indexing the "email" column in both tables before you run the query.

Comment: @RacilHilan It means, MySQL will soak up 100% of available memory. I have to restart MySQL or kill the process to recover.

Comment: You should update your question and add this info. Have you tried indexing the columns first?

Comment: @RacilHilan Indexing the email column solved the problem!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I will add it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is ok. To boost the performance, try indexing the "email" column in both tables before you run the query.

Without the indexes, it has to scan the entire 50k rows in both tables (so total of 100k rows) to find the matches.